# File mkdirs() method not working in android/java

Tags: java, android, file

I've been pulling out my hair on this for a while now.  The following method is supposed to download a file, and save it to the location specified on the hard drive.

```
private static void saveImage(Context context, boolean backgroundUpdate, URL url, File file) {

    if (!Tools.checkNetworkState(context, backgroundUpdate))
        return;

    // Get the image
    try {
        // Make the file
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        // Set up the connection
        URLConnection uCon = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = uCon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        // Download the data
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        // Write the bits to the file
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        os.write(baf.toByteArray());
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Any exception is probably a newtork faiilure, bail
        return;
    }
}
```

Also, if the file doesn't exist, it is supposed to make the directory for the file.  (And if there is another file already in that spot, it should just not do anything).  However, for some reason, the mkdirs() method never makes the directory.  I've tried everything from explicit parentheses, to explicitly making the parent file class, and nothing seems to work.  I'm fairly certain that the drive is writable, as it's only called after that has already been determined, also that is true after running through it while debugging.  So the method fails because the parent directories aren't made.  Can anyone tell me if there is anything wrong with the way I'm calling it?

Also, if it helps, here is the source for the file I'm calling it in:

https://github.com/LeifAndersen/NetCatch/blob/master/src/net/leifandersen/mobile/android/netcatch/services/RSSService.java

Thank you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are writing contents to your SD card hope you have added `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest

Comment: I can't believe it, that worked.  I feel like an idiot now.  On the other hand though, it was magically working other other revisions of the project, strange.  Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 13):

Please check with this, it may help you..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

enter tis permission in your manifest file.

Answer (score 5):

Further to [Kevin Day](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10973/kevin-day)'s reply, there is **another failure modality** that previous posts did not mention. It is that even if you have `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest, if you are trying to write to media such as `/mnt/sdcard` that is mounted externally as a USB gadget (i.e. you connected your device as an external disk to your PC with a USB cable) at the time you are trying to do the write, then you can't write to the /mnt/sdcard file system. In this case `FILE.mkdir` will return false. Obviously, if you are not checking the return code you wont see this problem until you get an `IOException` if you try to create a file in the directory that you think that you created. And if you don't create a file in this non-existent directory then the app will just silently fail.

I make this mistake constantly when debugging Android apps - forget that I can't both have the sdcard mounted externally and at the same time have my app write to it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that mkdirs is failing?  Why don't you check the return value of the mkdirs call and log an error message if it returns false?

```
if (!file.getParentFile().exists() && !file.getParentFile().mkdirs()){
  log("Unable to create " + file.getParentFile());
}
```

I suspect that you might be surprised with what the file was...

PS - and please do something with that error handler - at minimum, log the error.  Catching Exception and doing a silent return is horrible practice.

Comment: Good call on logging the error, that's a good idea and I've changed it now.  And it is claiming that it unable to create the file (inserting your error in their as suggested).