# mkdirs creates a file instead of creating a folder [JAVA]

Tags: java, android, file, unzip

I have a problem while unzipping a file, I get "open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)" error.. After debugging I found out that the problem is in this function:
After I determine that the current ZipEntry is a Directory, I call this function with its path:

```
private void dirChecker(String dir) {
        File FiledirChecker = new File(PATH + dir); // PATH+dir = /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Hafs

        if (!FiledirChecker.isDirectory())
            FiledirChecker.mkdirs();
    }
```

After this function is over, I browsed to Pictures directory, and Hafs isnt a Directory, instead its a 0 bytes file that is called "Hafs".

Why is this happening?

I should point out that for other directories (other than "Hafs"), mkdirs normally creates the folder! but only for this directory (Hafs) mkdirs doesnt make a directory but a file!

Comment: Have you checked [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543559/file-mkdirs-method-not-working-in-android-java)?

Comment: @assylias Yes, I already have that permission.

Comment: Run under a debugger, or add print statements, and find out whether your belief that File("Hafs").mkdirs() is actually being called (it may not be.) Likewise, add checks to the file-unzipping part of the code to make sure it's not accidentally being unzipped as a file (it probably is).

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill already did that, and indeed File("/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Hafs").mkdirs() gets called.. I dont know why only this directory is making the problem and not the 4 other directories!

Comment: But did you check to make sure a zero-size file isn't being created first? mkdirs() will fail silently -- it just returns boolean on failure -- and you're not checking the return value.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill That was the cause. I fixed a small bug in another place and now its working.. You were the first to comment with the correct answer, post an answer if u want that I accept ur answer.

Comment: I think it should be   if (FiledirChecker.isDirectory()) FiledirChecker.mkdirs();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because elsewhere in the code, an empty file has already been created.

Or the file is a leftover from your last run when your code couldn't create directories.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I miss something your file is already created somewhere else.
According to what I can see in your code
1) you check if the file is NOT a directory
2) if 1) is true you attempt to create complete directory structure and a directory with the same name as a file that may already exist.

Comment: This is a standard idiom. a `File` object represents a path, which possibly does not exist. If it's not a directory, then create it as such. It is true that if the file exists, but is not a directory, then this will try (and fail) to create the directory.

Comment: But, the correct approach would be to check `File.exists()`, NOT  `File.isDirectory()`