# Download youtube on Android

Tags: android, youtube

After reading this: [Code for download video from Youtube on Java, Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203047/code-for-download-video-from-youtube-on-java-android)

I found a way the obtain the youtube download link which is similar to this:
http://o-o---preferred---lax02s10---v9---lscache4.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=7XKwMrZklvQ&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&fexp=903903%

I tried to download the video using

```
    public void DownloadFromUrl(String DownloadUrl, String fileName) {
    Log.i("DownloadFromUrl","DownloadFromUrl"+DownloadUrl);

       try {
               File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();               

               File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/youlike");
               if(dir.exists()==false) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
               }

               URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl); //you can write here any link
               File file = new File(dir, fileName);

               long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
               Log.d("DownloadManager", "download begining");
               Log.d("DownloadManager", "download url:" + url);
               Log.d("DownloadManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);


               /* Open a connection to that URL. */
               URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
               Log.i("URLConnection","URLConnection Succeed");

               /*
                * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                */ 
               InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
               BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
               Log.i("BufferedInputStream","BufferedInputStream Succeed");

               /*
                * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
                */
               ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
               int current = 0;
               while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                  baf.append((byte) current);
                  Log.i("ByteArrayBuffer","ByteArrayBuffer Succeed");

               }


               /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
               FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
               Log.i("FileOutputStream","FileOutputStream initialized");
               fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
               Log.i("fos.write(baf.toByteArray());","fos.write(baf.toByteArray()); initialized");
               fos.flush();
               fos.close();
               Log.d("DownloadManager", "download ready in" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");

       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error: " + e);
       }

    }
```

But it returns an error message to me: java.io.FileNotFoundException
I tested the url and I am sure that it works. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Be careful that you adhere to the YouTube terms of service if you want to avoid possible litigation.

Comment: This is our school project. Our adviser asked us to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode you youtube download link before open the http connection

Comment: Good try! After the encoding, it shows java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found

Comment: Then take this code and have a nice grade :) https://github.com/lure/YoutubeGrabber

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you did not set write permission on external storgae? [File mkdirs() method not working in android/java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543559/file-mkdirs-method-not-working-in-android-java)

Comment: btw, you should write inputstream directly to your file outputstream because you might run out of memory trying to store them in memory first.

Comment: do you know what line give you the exception?

Comment: FileNotFoundException is thrown if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason (from java api)